# JPasswordField Turning into String but cannot Compare

Tags: java, arrays, swing, if-statement, jpasswordfield

Hello what i am trying to do here is to recieve the password the User has entered then compare it with the correct password in a if statement.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    String UsersStoredPassword = "hello";
    String UsersEnteredPassword = new String(PasswordField.getPassword());
    String Message = "The Password You Have Entered Is Correct";
    String Message1 = "You Have Entered The Wrong Password";

    if (event.getSource() == PasswordField)
    {
        if (UsersEnteredPassword == UsersStoredPassword)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Message);
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Message1);
        }

    }
}
```

However event thought the user typed in the correct password: "hello" it still shows message1: "You Have Entered The Wrong Password. I have tried doing this:

```
public class TheHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

        String UsersStoredPassword = "hello";
        String UsersEnteredPassword = new String(PasswordField.getPassword());
        String Message = "The Password You Have Entered Is Correct";
        String Message1 = "You Have Entered The Wrong Password";

        if (event.getSource() == PasswordField)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, UsersEnteredPassword);
        }
    }
}
```

and it shows UsersEnteredPassword as typed inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(UsersEnteredPassword == UsersStoredPassword){
```

to

```
if(UsersEnteredPassword.equals(UsersStoredPassword)){
```

on Objects manipulation

`==` means, pointing to the same address? or, its the exactly same object?

`equals` compares the content.

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing 2 `Strings` using the `==` operator which does not compare `String` content but this is not the real issue:

You've created a security vulnerability here.

**Explanation:** `JPassword.getText` was purposely deprecated to avoid using `Strings` in favor of using a `char[]` returned by `getPassword`.

When calling `getText` you get a String (immutable object) that may not be changed (except reflection) and so the password stays in the memory until garbage collected.

A char array however may be modified, so the password will really not stay in memory.

Use [`Array.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28char%5B%5D,%20char%5B%5D%29) instead

```
if (Arrays.equals(usersEnteredPassword.toCharArray()), 
      passwordField.getPassword()) {
      // password match!
}
```

Aside: Follow Java Naming conventions using a lowercase letter as a the initial letter for variable names as shown above. Read [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Answer (score 1):

Strings shouldn't be compared with `'=='`. You should always check equality  using `.equals(Object)` method for checking equality on any Objects. '==' is used to compare primitive datatype only, not Objects. '==' compares the equality of the **physical memory address** of the left and right operands. `.equals(Object)` checks whether both left and right operands are **meaningfully equivalent**. Hope this helps